# Code formatting with bash script

Tags: bash, format, continuation

I would like to search through a file and find all instances where the last non-blank character is a comma and move the line below that up one. Essentially, undoing line continuations like

```
private static final double SOME_NUMBERS[][] = {
    {1.0, -6.032174644509064E-23},
    {-0.25, -0.25},
    {-0.16624879837036133, -2.6033824355191673E-8}
};
```

and transforming that to

```
private static final double SOME_NUMBERS[][] = {
    {1.0, -6.032174644509064E-23}, {-0.25, -0.25}, {-0.16624879837036133, -2.6033824355191673E-8}
};
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything for this? This should, assuming you don't have any ranges/etc. in which to apply this and don't have any lines that you *don't* want this applied to, be a fairly simple `sed` or `awk` script.

Comment: I would think doing something like `sed s/,\n/ /g` (conceptually) would work, but I'm pretty novice with sed. Also, this only would work for `,\n` and not `,       \n` and I would like it to handle any amount of spaces between `,` and `\n`

Comment: Other then that `sed` works on a line-by-line basis and so can't match `\n` like that (by default), yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mjswartz suggests in the comments, we need a sed substitution command like `s/,\n/ /g`.  That, however, does not work by itself because, by default, sed reads in only one line at a time.  We can fix that by reading in the whole file first and then doing the substitution:

```
$ sed 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/,[[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*/, /g;' file
private static final double SOME_NUMBERS[][] = {
    {1.0, -6.032174644509064E-23}, {-0.25, -0.25}, {-0.16624879837036133, -2.6033824355191673E-8}
};
```

Because this reads in the whole file at once, this is not a good approach for huge files.

The above was tested with GNU sed.

#### How it works

- `H;1h;$!d;x;`

  This series of commands reads in the whole file.  It is probably simplest to think of this as an idiom.  If you really want to know the gory details:

  - `H` - Append current line to hold space
  - `1h`  - If this is the first line, overwrite the hold space with it
  - `$!d` - If this is not the last line, delete pattern space and jump to the next line.
  - `x`  - Exchange hold and pattern space to put whole file in pattern space
- `s/,[[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*/, /g`

  This looks for lines that end with a comma, optionally followed by blanks, followed by a newline and replaces that, and any leading space on the following line, with a comma and a single space.

Comment: This looks like it replaces the commas whereas I would like to keep them. What would I tweak to get `,\n` to turn into `, `? Sorry if that was not clear

Comment: @mjswartz Thanks for spotting that.  It is fixed: the solution now keeps commas.

Answer (score 2):

I think for large files `awk` would be better:

```
awk -vRS=", *\n" -vORS=", " '1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

On lua-shell, just write like this:

```
function nextlineup()
    vim:normal("j^y$k$pjddk")
end

vim:open("code.txt")
vim:normal("G")
while vim:k() do
    vim:normal("$") 
    if(vim.currc == string.byte(',')) nextlineup();
end
```

If you are not familier with vim ,this script seems a bit scary and not robust. In fact, every operation in it is precise(and much quicker, because tey are built-in functions). 
Since you are processing a code file,　i suggest you try it.

[here is a demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx9G5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl solution.
    cat file | perl -e '{$c = 0; while () { s/^\s+/ / if ($c); s/,\s*$/,/; print($_); $c = (m/,\s*$/) ? 1: 0; }}'